# Content Scripts causing memory leak

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that has a background page, and creates an app page when you click on a button that the content scripts adds to a page. Once the app window is opened, the extension opens an iframe and acts like a robot crawling the certain site and this helps my clients get additional work/money. This crawling process it the only task the extension has.

As the iframe changes from page to page, the content scripts listed in my manifest.json reload each time. This is expected, but it is causing a memory leak. After a while of the app running my people experience a dramatically slow response time. When I look at the scripts section of the DevTools, each of the scripts listed in my Manifest are there hundreds of times (once per page load I am guessing), as are the scripts that the Extension loads natively. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening, so that I can avoid these memory issues for my clients?

Comment: [Chromium's bug reporting guidelines](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines)

Comment: You feel confident that this is a bug?

Comment: That's for you to decide