# Chrome extension using jQuery leaks memory

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, memory-leaks, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I'm currently developing an extension that uses content scripts (jquery is one of content scripts) and I have noticed that page gets slow with long use. Page is not dynamic, but rather it refreshes on every click (goes to different page on button click). If I open Task Manager I can clearly see that content scripts are responsible for memory leak.

Extension disabled (after ~20 refreshes)

[image: Extension disabled]

Enabled (after ~20 refreshes)

[image: Extension enabled]

I have narrowed leak down to jQuery & jQueryUI scripts by removing all other scripts and confirming that by removing jQuery scripts ass well so that then leak is not present anymore.

I'm using latest version of jQuery and I don't see this leak in other pages that use it.

Is there anything I can do to at least reduce memory leaks?

**-- EDIT**

Extension is [Project-Axeman](https://github.com/JustBuild/Project-Axeman) so you can take a look if you think it's something else that leaks.

**-- UPDATE**

I have replaced jQuery with beta version and problem persists...

Comment: Just because an extension that uses jQuery has a leak, it does not mean that jQuery has a leak.

Comment: I don't think jQuery has a leak, plus in the Github repository your jQuery is a blank file. Other than just removing the scripts, what have you done so far to debug your application?

Comment: @jjperezaguinaga jQuery script isn't blank, it's minimized and doesn't show properly under github (try using horizontal scroll). To be honest, this is my first js project so I'm not into memory analysis yet. I have took heap snapshot but can't read anything from it.

Comment: Your mention that your application "`refreshes on every click`" reminds me of [Content Scripts causing memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363992/content-scripts-causing-memory-leak), in which a content script that was constantly re-injected into a reloading iframe caused a browser-level memory leak. It's quite possible that jQuery has absolutely nothing to do with your leak.

Comment: @apsillers I have corrected mistake - on click, page navigates to another and there it re-injects content script (iframe is not used). Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

There are Heap Profile [**`Demo's`**](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling-summary) using developer tools of chrome, with these you can get

- Overview of the [space](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling-summary) occupied by the objects
- [Garbage](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling-comparison) left by actions through multiple invocations
- [Inspect](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling-containment) variables of closures, and peek into objects internals
- Uncovering [DOM Leaks](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling-dom-leaks)
  and lot more

How ever, there are some other options in task manager, which give more detail than **abstract memory value**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for info. I have take a look under other categories and I can see that "JavaScript memory" is increasing on each refresh (other stays somewhat same) and that all used memory is private memory. Same thing happens when I remove application scripts (only jquery/UI left), but there is no leak when jQuery scripts are removed too... TM says 114,912K(94,291K live) for JavaScript memory

Comment: Using Heap Profiler and comaring two snapshots between one refresh, most memory delta is on (array) and (compiled code). I don't think compiled code should rise that much (+96 812) on each refresh and array (+73 908)